# Limit involving the totient function and combination

Tags: limits-and-convergence, nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

Hi,

Do you think the following limits are correct?

$\displaystyle\lim_{d\to\infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{d} {\phi(N) \choose  k} {d-1 \choose k-1}}{\phi(N)^d}=0$

$\displaystyle\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{d} {\phi(N) \choose  k} {d-1 \choose k-1}}{\phi(N)^d}=c$

I plotted the equations and guessed the results according to the graphs but I could not prove them mathematically by myself. Any hints would be appreciated. Graphs are as follows:

http://deniz.cs.utsa.edu/plots/d_vs_Eq.jpeg

http://deniz.cs.utsa.edu/plots/N_vs_Eq.jpeg

Thanks,

Comment: I don't understand your first graph at all.  For fixed $N$ and $d$, the resulting expression is a rational number with denominator $\phi(N)$.  So, for example, when $N = 7$ it's a rational number with denominator 6.  Where are you getting values like $10^{-10}$ from?

Comment: I am sorry but there was a typo, i edited now, the denominator should be $\phi(N)^d$. Sorry again!

Comment: Also posted in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6803/limit-involving-the-totient-function-and-combination

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We have $$\sum_{k = 1}^d \binom{\phi(N)}{k} \binom{d - 1}{k - 1} = \binom{d + \phi(N) - 1}{d}$$ (this is the Vandermonde identity).  Thus, with $N$ fixed the numerator of your fraction is polynomial in $d$ and so the first result follows (except for $N = 1, 2$).

Edited to add:
Okay, and the second result follows by the same analysis, since $\phi(N) \to \infty$ as $N \to \infty$.  In particular, the resulting constant is $\frac{1}{d!}$.